# Match Cells in column, then subtracting a value from two different tabs

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am working with google-sheets, I am trying to right a formula that will look for similar Location ID and subtract the quantity from the similar cells. I attached a picture to explain what the formula should do.

[image: []

Comment: look into SUMIFS

Comment: =SUMIF(A2:A4,TabA!A2,B2:B4)-TabA!B2 , I have tried this but it does not give me a correct answer

Comment: `=SUMIF(TabA!$A$2:$A$4,A2,TabA!$B$2:$B$4)-A2`

Comment: It is not working

Comment: What does `It is not working` mean?  I will need more details.

Comment: Function minus parameter 2 expects number values. But '0201A' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number. And if I change it to  =SUMIF(TabA!$A$2:$A$4,B2,TabA!$B$2:$B$4)-B2 it gives me a wrong answer.

Comment: `=B2 - SUMIF(TabA!$A$2:$A$4,A2,TabA!$B$2:$B$4)`

Comment: Prefect, thank you so much!!!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Please tag as Excel

Answer (score 0):

paste in **TabB!C2**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,B2:b-IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, TabA!A:B, 2, 0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for Quantity in Table1 using Vlookup and do the calculation

`=VLOOKUP(D4,$A$4:$B6,2,FALSE)`

And in the Result column, do the difference using `=E4-F4`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution provided by [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803262/match-cells-in-column-then-subtracting-a-value-from-two-different-tabs#comment109322046_61803262) to make it more visible:

`=B2 - SUMIF(TabA!$A$2:$A$4,A2,TabA!$B$2:$B$4)`